# Compression Level 2 Folders and Files, within Level 1 folder location, as individual 7Z archives

Tags: linux, bash, zsh, ubuntu-18.04, 7zip

Am generating DB or both historic and current build development files into a local repo.  I need a bash script (or other) that will run through the import folder and recursively compress all level 2 files and directories into their own/individual 7z files.

On a periodic basis there will be  number of folders, and some files, in a master directory (Level 1) during development.  The folders/files in that directory (Level 2) are all for different approaches or builds.  Need to run a script which will compress each/all of the Level 2 Files and Folders, as a high compression 7Z file, using the original name without having to do it file/file or folder/folder one by one.  Whatever the Level 3+ (recursive) files/folders are that exist with the Level 2 Folders, shall compress within the Level 2 constraint.

Even better, I would like to be able to change/assign the location of the new save location:
.
.

***Example:***

**E: Drive/Path/To Parent Folder (Level 1)**

- Folder A (level 2)
- *_________Sub Files A1 thru Zz*
- *_________Sub Folders A2 thru Zz*
- File B (level 2)
- Folder C (level 2)
- *_________Sub Files C1 thru Zz*
- *_________Sub Folders C2 thru Zz*
- File D (level 2)

*Compress to (other drive/location):*

**G: Drive/Path/To Archive Folder**

- Folder A.7z
- File B.7z
- Folder C.7z
- File D.7z

There may be many files/folders in the original level 1 master folder.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow (SO). [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.